# Find the user name who killed the Hadoop job

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Is there a way to find the name of the user who killed the `Hadoop` job?
I have no root access on the cluster `Hadoop 2.6.0` nodes so I can only use the Hadoop command line tools and scrutinize the logs.
I've checked the logs and tried using `mapred job -history [jhist file]` but couldn't find the user name.

Comment: When I check in my yarn logs, I see the error "2015-10-12 02:57:23,905 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job: Job job_1444238392305_0019 failed with state KILLED due to: Application killed by user."  It just contains the string "Application killed by user." It does not contain the name of the user who killed the application. I checked the code. In the code also, I see the statement "return "Application killed by user.";" in getAppKilledDiagnostics() function. In the YARNRM's UI page for the application, I just see the error: " Diagnostics: Application killed by user".

Comment: Manjunath, thanks for your effort!

Answer (score -3):

Open a web browser and paste the following into the address bar replacing URL with the public DNS of the machine where the resource manager is running, making sure not to type the angle brackets:

URL:8088/cluster/apps/KILLED

You will see the User name in the second column in the lower portion of the screen where the killed apps are listed